# How to Display the name of singer who has the maximum number of songs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014, rdbms

Hi I am beginner and i want to Show that singer name who has maximum number of songs in songs table but i failed to do this because subquery cannot return two values at a time. how can i solve this problem.  Below code shows this error -> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

here is my code ->

```
SELECT Singer_Name
FROM Singer
WHERE Singer_id IN(SELECT TOP 1 Singer.Singer_id,COUNT(SongTitle) TotalSounds 
                    FROM Singer,Songs
                    WHERE Songs.Singer_id=Singer.Singer_id
                    GROUP BY Singer.Singer_id
                    ORDER BY TotalSounds DESC)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close to a workable solution. The issue is you were doing the subquery in the where clause, trying to limit your results that way, where you could just return the full list of names and number of songs and just pick the top one after ordering by the count:

```
SELECT TOP 1 SingerName FROM (SELECT Singer.Singer_Name, count(1) as TotalSounds 
FROM Singer 
JOIN Songs
ON Songs.Singer_id=Singer.Singer_id
GROUP BY Singer.Singer_Name, Singer.Singer_id) ss
ORDER BY TotalSounds DESC
```

If you have a tie for first place, and want to return both names, you make it `TOP 1 WITH TIES` otherwise it will just grab the first one, arbitrarily breaking the tie by the order they appear in the table (likely by Singer_id)

Comment: Thank you for reply it's working but it is not showing the max song singer name it's show just first Singer_id  1  singer name. if i remove the singer with id 1 then it's showing 2 singer_id singer name. not the max sound singer name

Comment: Thank you very much, i solved this problem by editing this code. Can explain with is ss

Comment: @RajanJosan Ahh yes I see the issue, sorry there was not supposed to be a TOP 1 in the subquery

Comment: Hi @Andrew i am not able to show singer name who has same number of songs how can i do this can you help pls

Comment: I find it Just Add After SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES then it will show the same maximum songs singer name.

Comment: @RajanJosan in my answer i say how to return `WITH TIES`

Comment: Ohh sorry i didn't see it. Thank you : )

Answer (score 1):

#### This should do the trick:

```
SELECT TOP 1 n.Singer_Name, count(*) as Song_Count
    FROM Songs s
    INNER JOIN Singer n on n.Singer_id = s.Singer_id
    GROUP BY n.Singer_id, n.Singer_Name
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

I added n.Singer_id to the group by on the off-chance that two singers could have the same name.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **group by** statement like this:

```
SELECT Singer_Name, count(SongTitle) c FROM Singer 
  join Song on Song.singer_id = Singer.singer_id 
  group by Singer_Name
  ORDER BY c desc limit 1;
```

Comment: LIMIT is MySQL, this is MsSQL

Comment: Also missing the join to songs.

Comment: @RajanJosan and what exactly is SQL only language?

Comment: Thank you for reply i got the solution above.